# What is the probability that at least 10 cards go by before the first jack?

Tags: probability

Suppose we keep dealing cards from an ordinary 52-card deck until the first jack
appears. What is the probability that at least 10 cards go by before the first jack?

---

The outcome space is ${52\choose10}$ Since you choosing $10$ spots from $52$ cards. Now how do I determine the probability that at least 10 card by by before the first jack?

There are 4 jacks in a 52 card deck. Pretty sure I have to figure out how many ways can I select 10 cards that are not jacks at the top. Unsure how do I go about this visually.

Comment: So essentially you get no Jacks the first 9 goes. Then a Jack. So something like $\frac {52-4}{52} \frac {51-4}{51} \cdot \cdot \cdot \frac {4}{43}$. So we multiply all the times we don't get it in 9 goes and then all the ways we could get it in the 10th go.

Comment: $$P(1st \ Jack \ on \ n^{th} \ card)= \prod_{i=52}^{52-n+1} \frac {i-4}{i} \cdot \frac 4{52-n}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- There are ${52 \choose 10}$ equally probably sets of ten cards chosen from a full pack
- There are ${48 \choose 10}$ equally probably sets of ten cards chosen from a full pack excluding the four Jacks

Answer (score 2):

The probability that the first card is not a Jack is 48/52. If this happens, the probability that the second card is not a Jack either is 47/51. The probability that none of the first ten are Jacks is 
$$\frac{48.47.46\ldots 39}{52.51.50\ldots 43}$$
$$=\frac{48!42!}{38!52!}=0.4134453782$$

Comment: But isn't it the probability at *least* 10 cards go before a jack? So wouldn't we have to find the probability of 0, 1, 2, ... 9 cards before a jack and then subtract that from 1?